# Change the location of the messenger bubble

Tags: facebook-messenger

I want to know if it is possible to change the location of the messenger bubble on my site by modifying the CSS code for example.
How to do it exactly if it is possible?

Comment: Are you talking about Facebook's Customer Chat SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the .fb-customerchat and .fb_dialog classes to modify the position of the icon and dialog even though not recommended by FB since this may break linked functionalities or cross-browser rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code in my main css file to add some padding to the bubble in the mobile view.

```
.fb_dialog_mobile .fb_dialog_content > iframe {
  bottom: 76px !important;
}
```

You can inspect element and see the exact class names for the elements as above not be the same case you are looking for. However the  element cannot be referenced directly as it doesn't have a class name.